# Unable to Accept Debit Card Information in CodeIgniter-3 CRUD Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, codeigniter-3, google-cloud-logging

I am currently working on a small CRUD project using the CodeIgniter-3 framework. While implementing the functionality to accept debit card information, I encountered an issue. Unfortunately, the system does not accept my debit card, and I am unsure about the cause of this problem.

Here's a brief description of my setup:

Framework: CodeIgniter-3
Payment Method: Debit Card
Issue: Debit card information not being accepted
I have followed the standard implementation guidelines for accepting debit card information, but for some reason, it's not working as expected. I would appreciate any insights or guidance on how to resolve this issue.

Here are the specific steps I have taken so far:

Created a form to collect debit card details (card number, expiration date, CVV, etc.).
Implemented validation rules for the debit card form fields.
Utilized CodeIgniter's form validation library to validate the debit card information.
Used a secure connection (HTTPS) for the form submission.
Double-checked the card number, expiration date, and CVV for accuracy.
Ensured that my card is valid and active.
Despite following these steps, the system refuses to accept my debit card information. I have also checked if there are any specific requirements or restrictions related to debit cards within the CodeIgniter framework, but haven't found any relevant information.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance in identifying the possible reasons behind this issue or any suggestions on how to troubleshoot it effectively. Thank you in advance for your help!

Note: Please feel free to ask for any additional details or code snippets if required.